# How do I Convert a txt file to an array of floats (in c#)?

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I've read a file into a variable in my c# project and want to convert it into an array of floats.

Here's a sample of the txt file:

```
-5.673

10.543

-0.322

10.048
```

The file contains a number, followed by a blank line and another number.

I've used the following code to read the file into my project:

```
var numbers = File.ReadAllLines(@"numbers.txt")
```

How would i convert `numbers` into a float array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Linq` and `float.Parse()`:

```
var floats = numbers.Where(s => s != String.Empty).Select(s => float.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
```

But if you have incorrect data in file you will get exception. To check if value is correct `float` use `float.TryParse()`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of variable `var` is `String[]` so in this case you can get the values from the even positions of the array and then cast to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program should loop through each line in the file which are currently stored in the `numbers` variable, which is of type `String[]`, check if the value of the line is empty, and if not, convert it to a float and add it to our array of floats.

Bringing this all together would look something like this:

```
string[] numbers = File.ReadAllLines(@"numbers.txt");

// Create a list we can add the numbers we're parsing to. 
List<float> parsedNumbers = new List<float>() ;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) 
{
    // Check if the current number is an empty line
    if (numbers[i].IsNullOrEmpty()) 
    {
        continue;
    }
    // If not, try to convert the value to a float
    if (float.TryParse(numbers[i], out float parsedValue))
    {
        // If the conversion was successful, add it to the parsed float list 
        parsedNumbers.Add(parsedValue);
    }
} 

// Convert the list to an array
float[] floatArray = new float[parsedNumbers.Length];
```